# NodeJS MongoDb find duplicate values and Modify increment

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, find

I have a collection called books that has objects-- isbn, author, number of books `(num)`, publisher and so on.
Just after I get the book information from my view, I want to check if the isbn of the book already exists and if so I want t increment the number of books. However, the number never increments even if its the same book. Anyone knows why?

```
var collection = db.collection('books');

        var item=collection.findAndModify({
        query: { isbn: req.body.isbn13 },
        update: { $inc: { num: 1 } },
        });
        if(item==null)
        {add the info to the database}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using a callback function to check if the item is null or not found,

https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/markdown-docs/insert.html

```
var collection = db.collection('books');

        var item=collection.findAndModify({
        query: { isbn: req.body.isbn13 },
        update: { $inc: { num: 1 } },
        }, function(err, object) 
{
//check here & add the info to the database
});
```